# Unable to connect to local SQL Server after ending tasks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

I'm unable to connect to my local server after I accidentally ended some SQL Server related tasks in Task Manager.

I found out that my my SQL Server Agent is not running, and unable to make it to run, below is the message shown.

[image]

Any idea about resolving the problem?

[image]

```
    2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 12.0.2000.8 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 8736
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE.
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
2016-02-25 22:35:09 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)
```

Comment: Have you started back SQL server service itself prior to starting agent? Anyway, there is a big chance that full restart of computer will resolve the issue.

Comment: I agree! A restart to the computer should solve all the problems.

Comment: I have the SQL Server it self as well as the whole computer, I even uninstalled all the component of SQL Server and reinstalled it completely, but nothing resolved the problem @CiucaS

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I have the SQL Server it self as well as the whole computer, I even uninstalled all the component of SQL Server and reinstalled it completely, but nothing resolved the problem

Comment: Behaviour you're describing can't be result of simple "stopping sql server related tasks" - especially if you've prefromed clean reinstallation. Try to ask extended version of your question at dba.stackexchange.com since it is slightly offtopic at StackOverflow.

Comment: Take a look at the agent's log file.  The most recent is named SQLAGENT.OUT and is typically found under %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.<version>\MSSQL\LOG.  What is being written there?

Comment: I have updated it on my post @ScrapingInfinity

Comment: Based on the log file, my answer is no longer suitable for this problem. I'm deleting it OP

Comment: @JustDoIt alright, thanks anyway!

Comment: And that is a programming question because? Of topic here.

Comment: Because my database connected asp.net project can't be run due to this severe problem? :( @TomTom

Comment: Ok, and if you get sick with a cold and are programming that also is a programming problem? Mental failure - you have a system administration problem. NOTHING here is programming.

Comment: If you are not intended to help, pls just ignore the post, or you can just flag me off. I'm new here and I saw there's bunch of people posted the related issues, does that means they are all having the issues u mentioned? Be helpful and get a life pls. I didn't mean to insult you. @TomTom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answering my question!

I eventually solve the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling it again.

For this time, I go on Control Panel > Programs and Features > and choose on Microsoft SQL Server 2014 to be uninstalled, not sure why it didnt work this way for my previous reinstall, but it works for now!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error messages in your Sql Agent's log file, it appears that the SQL Engine is starting, at least.  Otherwise, you wouldn't be seeing messages about execute permissions being denied (instead you'd probably be seeing some messages about not being able to contact the server).

What you need to do now is either: Grant the user account that is being used to run the SQL Agent the rights it needs, or switch to an account that already has those rights.

You can see from your log file that the account current being used is NT AUTHORITY/LOCAL SERVICE.  To change the user account to something else: Open Control Panel -> Administration -> Services, right- click on the SQL Server Agent service, select Properties, click the Log On tab, and change to a different user account.

To grant permissions to the existing account:  Open SQL Server Management Studio, and log in to your database with a working account. Navigate to Security -> Logins, right click on the name of the user that currently runs SQL Server Agent, and select Properties.... for absolute minimum permissions to run the Agent, head to User Mapping, select the MSDB database, and pick one of the SQL Agent fixed accounts ([as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx)).  (Alternatively, you can pick Server Roles, set it as a sysadmin and call it a day--but only if you don't care too much about security on this server...)

Comment: I don't have any other user account, and I can't create a new account either1....

Comment: Are you saying you cannot log in to the SQL server instance at all?  Have you tried starting it in [single user mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx)?  Any member of the computer's local Administrators group can get into SQL this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please always use the **SQL Server 2008 Configuration Manager** to open SQL service. Never use windows service to open SQL services.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the list of lessons learned...

Sql Server Configuration Manager -> then aliases

During some documentation, trying to create a ODBC file connection (just for screenshots), had actually also created a lot of aliases that redirected all connections to odd places.

Deleting all of the aliases (don't do this unless you know what you are doing, or are on e dev/test system), actually helped.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN RESTART SQLSERVER if you get errors from shutting down using the task manager.

1. Signin to the computer hosting the instance of SQL Server.
2. Start SQL Server Configuration Manager.
3. In the left pane, select SQL Server Services.
4. In the right pane, verify the name of the instance of the database engine.
5. the STATE of your sqlserver agent will show STOPPED. you want it to show RUNNING
6. Right click on SQL SERVER AGENT and select START.
7. If START is grayed out, scroll down to Properties >> Service>> Start mode>> Manual>> apply
8. Return to 6 and select START
9. You can also stop SQLSERVER running in the background and needlessly consuming memory using this configuration manager also.

[Snapshot of SQLSERVER Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3kDi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**No need to uninstall at all** just follow the shortcut step below-

1. Open task manager(or type ctrl+shift+esc)
2. Click on "service" option
3. search mysql.
   Now you can see mySQL80. Start running it, by right click , then run.

Now it start running, and you can access it's server.